# Dynamically create PHP class functions

Tags: php

I'd like to iterate over an array and dynamically create functions based on each item. My pseudocode:

```
$array = array('one', 'two', 'three');

foreach ($array as $item) {
    public function $item() {
        return 'Test'.$item;
    }
}
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Can i ask why you want to create this functions

Comment: Adding too much dynamic can make a program unreadable - which is equivalent to unmaintainable. Can you go into details of what you have and what you want to get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Create Instance Method in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231365/dynamically-create-instance-method-in-php)

Comment: @Baba and Sven Simple, he is asking a good point because some functions seems to be same with only difference of one word. We are duplicating the code. So best way is write a dynamic code.

Answer (score 33):

Instead of "creating" functions, you can use the magic method [`__call()`](http://php.net/__call), so that when you call a "non-existent" function, you can handle it and do the right action.

Something like this:

```
class MyClass{
    private $array = array('one', 'two', 'three');

    function __call($func, $params){
        if(in_array($func, $this->array)){
            return 'Test'.$func;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
$a = new MyClass;
$a->one(); // Testone
$a->four(); // null
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/73mSh

**EDIT**: If you are using PHP 5.3+, you actually *can* do what you are trying to do in your question!

```
class MyClass{
    private $array = array('one', 'two', 'three');

    function __construct(){
        foreach ($this->array as $item) {
            $this->$item = function() use($item){
                return 'Test'.$item;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This does work, except that you can't call `$a->one()` directly, you need to [save it as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7067536/206403).

```
$a = new MyClass;
$x = $a->one;
$x() // Testone
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ayGsTu

Comment: @NullUserException: Thanks for adding the fact that `__call()` is a "magic method".

Comment: You can also use the magic `__get()` function to call closures / callbacks functions then:, see [Dynamically Create Instance Method in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231365/dynamically-create-instance-method-in-php) - If you really think `__call()` or `__get()` is what has been asked for, please suggest an existing question as a duplicate.

Comment: How can you PHP docblock this so editor does not warn about "non existing functions"?

Answer (score 4):

```
class MethodTest
{
    private $_methods = array();

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_methods)) {
            $this->_methods[$name]($arguments);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_methods[$name] = $arguments[0];
        }
    }
}

$obj = new MethodTest;

$array = array('one', 'two', 'three');

foreach ($array as $item) 
{
    // Dynamic creation
    $obj->$item((function ($a){ echo "Test: ".$a[0]."\n"; }));
    // Calling
    $obj->$item($item);
}
```

The above example will output:

```
Test: one
Test: two
Test: three
```

Comment: is there a way to get around the `$a[0]` and to just have `$a` ?

Comment: @duck class MethodTest
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        echo ""
            . "Method: ".$name."\n"
            . (!empty($arguments) ? "Parameters: ". implode(', ', $arguments) : "No parameter!"). "\n";
    }
}

$obj = new MethodTest;

$obj->ExecTest('par 1', 'par 2', 'others ...');

$obj->ExecTest();