# How to call class methods that do not exist in php?

Tags: php, oop, magento, magic-methods, overriding

I just want to create function just like `getFieldname()` that is in magento.

For Ex:

**In Magento**

`getId()` - returns value of `ID` field

`getName()` - returns value of `Name` field

How can I create like that function? Kindly help me in this case..

I want to do just Like Below code,

```
Class Called{
    $list=array();
    function __construct() {
        
        $this->list["name"]="vivek";
        $this->list["id"]="1";
    }
    function get(){
        echo $this->list[$fieldname];
    }

}

$instance=new Called();

$instance->getId();
$instance->getName();
```

Comment: Share your exact scenario please. do you want to override "a super class method" or just "a defined function"? and take a look at this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994758/what-is-function-overloading-and-overriding-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically create PHP class functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868066/dynamically-create-php-class-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **magic method** **`__call`** to solved your situation

```
<?php
class Called
{
    private $list = array('Id' => 1, 'Name' => 'Vivek Aasaithambi');

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $field = substr($name, 3);
        echo $this->list[$field];
    }
}

$obj = new Called();
$obj->getId();
echo "<br/>\n";
$obj->getName();

?>
```

You can read more about **`__call`** in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Answer (score 3):

Check the implementation of `Varien_Object`, the `__call` method is probably what you are looking for, I think. http://freegento.com/doc/de/d24/_object_8php-source.html

This will basically "capture" any non-existing method calls and if they are in the shape `$this->getWhateverField`, will try to access that property. With minor tweaks should work for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want:

Your class should be inherited from another class (Super class) which defines your required methods.

```
class Super {

    public function getId(){
        return $this->list["id"];
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->list["name"];
    }

}

class Called extends Super {

    var $list = array();

    function __construct() {

        $this->list["name"]="vivek";
        $this->list["id"]="1";
    }
}

$instance=new Called();

echo $instance->getId(); // 1
echo $instance->getName(); //vivek
```

Comment: Nope.. Array would be dynamic... So I cant write functions as you did @Babak T

Comment: Then what you need is not method overriding! is called "dynamic method creating".