# how to create a method on the fly in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm writing a control panel for my image site. I have a controller called category which looks like this:

```
class category extends ci_controller
{
    function index(){}// the default and when it called it returns all categories 

    function edit(){}

    function delete(){}

    function get_posts($id)//to get all the posts associated with submitted category name
    { 

    }
}
```

What I need is when I call `http://mysite/category/category_name` I get all the posts without having to call the get_posts() method having to call it from the url.

I want to do it without using the .haccess file or route.

Is there a way to create a method on the fly in CodeIgniter?

Comment: This is exactly what routes are for...

Comment: ... see here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: i know that, i want you to give me route condition that distinguishe  between controller methods and category manes

Comment: $route['category/(:any)'] = 'category/get_posts/$1';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function index(){
    $category = $this->uri->segment(2);
    if($category)
    {
        get_posts($category); // you need to get id in there or before. 
    }

    // handle view stuff here

}
```

The way I read your request is that you want index to handle everything based on whether or not there is a category in a uri segment. You COULD do it that way but really, why would you?

It is illogical to insist on NOT using a normal feature of a framework without explaining exactly why you don't want to. If you have access to this controller, you have access to routes. So why don't you want to use them?

EDIT

```
$route['category/:any'] = "category/get_posts";
```

That WOULD send edit and delete to get_posts, but you could also just define those above the category route

```
$route['category/edit/:num'] = "category/edit";
$route['category/delete/:num'] = "category/delete";
$route['category/:any'] = "category/get_posts";
```

That would resolve for the edit and delete before the category fetch. Since you only have 2 methods that conflict then this shouldn't really be that much of a concern.

Comment: if i use something like $route['category/:any']="some cntroller/method"; it route all other method to same controller/method
i want just cat name to go to correct method

Comment: thanks this worked well. but no one answers this: is there away to create a method on the fly in ci

Comment: See: [Dynamically Create Instance Method in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231365/dynamically-create-instance-method-in-php)

Comment: @samutz - an interesting option but not really a good idea in CI since understanding the routes system is much better than working around a minor misunderstanding.

Comment: @Kai Qing I agree, but mohammed seems determined to not use routes.

Answer (score 0):

To create method on the fly yii is the best among PHP framework.Quite simple and powerful with Gii & CRUD

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app

But I am a big CI fan not Yii. yii is also cool though.

but Codeigniter has an alternative , web solution.

http://formigniter.org/ here.