# How to create a dynamically named method

Tags: dynamic

for example:

```
class Foo() {
    const BAR_FUNC = 'bar';
    //!!!the following function name needs to use self::BAR_FUNC rather than "hardcoded"     text "bar" in the function name
    function get_default_bar() {
        return 'this is my bar';
    }
}
```

### https://www.php.net/functions.variable-functions has an example of dynamically named function, but it doesn't work for class method:

Create and call a dynamically named function

```
$tmp = "foo";
$$tmp = function() {
    global $tmp;
    echo $tmp;
}; 

$$tmp();
```

### Outputs "foo"

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is for calling a function based on a dynamic name, not creating a function based on a dynamic name.

There is an existing answer at [Dynamically Create Instance Method in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231365/dynamically-create-instance-method-in-php)